# Where did access_token saved?

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I know The `security Oauth2` will send `Access_token` to `Client App`,so that the `Client APP` could use these `access_token` go to get the service.
My question is : How do the `service` know that the `access_token` sent by `Client` is right??
In the pic below,seems like the `security Oauth2` and `service` use `DB/MEMORY` communicate
Do `security Oauth2`save access_token here to tell `service` which one is right??
Where can I find in the code of these part??
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From within the client application, most likely, you are going to use a RestTemplate to communicate with the Resource Server. To make use of Spring's oauth capabilities, your rest template has to extend Spring's OAuth  `Oauth2RestTemplate`. One of the fields of this RestTemplate implementation is `Oauth2ClientContext`. This is where Spring stores the access_token.

By the time the RestClient will call the resource endpoint, a request object is built containing the OAuth access token.

Check this method out: `OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod method)`

Comment: excuse me, so you mean the access_token us saved in client application??

Comment: There are actually two tokens that are saved: `access_token` and `refresh_token`. The access token has a time to live (minutes/hours) much shorter than the refresh token (months/years). The client application will use the access token to authenticate itself to the oauth provider. If that access token is expired, it will use the refresh token to get a new access token and use the new one to get access on the server.

So yes, both are persisted in the client app.

Comment: For further information, you can check the oauth specs: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4 for access token and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.5 for refresh token.